# Condition is ignored using .where() in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the Bonus Pay given to our Courier's based on their `Success Rate` which is based off the number of `Eligible` orders they've successfully delivered.

Here's my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'path\filename.xlsx')


df['DeliveredAt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DeliveredAt'].astype(str))

df['Date'] = df['DeliveredAt'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%y')

df['Total Orders'] = df['OrderNumber']

df['Total Orders'] = 1

df['Eligible'] = df['DeliveryOnTime'].isin(["On-time", "Early"])

df['Success Rate'] = (df['Eligible']/df['Total Orders'])*100

df['Bonus'] = df['Eligible'].mul(1.2).where(df['Success Rate'] >= 95)

per_day = df.groupby(['Date', 'Courier']).agg({'Success Rate': 'mean', 'Total Orders': 'count', 'Eligible': 'sum', 'Incentive': 'sum'})

per_courier = df.groupby('Courier').agg({'Total Orders': 'count', 'Incentive': 'sum'})
```

I'm having issues with

```
df['Bonus'] = df['Eligible'].mul(1.2).where(df['Success Rate'] >= 95)
```

It seems to ignore the condition that `Success Rate` has to be over 95 for it to qualify for a Bonus. Right now, each row has a Bonus pay which is calculated from the number of `Eligible` * 1.2 regardless of the success rate value.

**Sample Data:**

```
data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
         'DeliveryOnTime': ["On-time", "Late", "Early", "On-time", "On-time", "Late", "Early", "Early", "Late"],
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#For the sake of example data, the count of `DeliveryOnTime` will be the total number of orders. 
df['Total Orders'] = df['DeliveryOnTime'].count() 
df['Eligible'] = df['DeliveryOnTime'].isin(["On-time", "Early"])
df['Success Rate'] = (df['Eligible']/df['Total Orders'])*100
df['Bonus'] = df['Eligible'].mul(1.2).where(df['Success Rate'] >= 95)
```

**Current Output**

```
    ID       Eligible      Total Orders    Success Rate   Bonus
     1           2              3            66.66         2.4
     2           2              2             100          2.4
     3           0              1              0            0
     4           1              1             100          1.2
     5           1              2              50          1.2
```

This is wrong as ID 1 and 5 should not have any `Bonus` at all with the `Success Rate` being lower than 95.

**Expected Output**

```
ID       Eligible     Total Orders    Success Rate    Bonus
 1           2              3            66.66          0
 2           2              2             100          2.4
 3           0              1              0            0
 4           1              1             100          1.2
 5           1              2              50           0
```

I'm not sure if it's something I have to change in the `Per_day` or `Per_courier` section of the `.groupby()` as that seems to be where most of my issues have occurred when writing this code.

Thanks

Comment: please rework your question to put emphasis on your minimal reproducible example (provide the expected output)

Comment: @mozway Hi thanks for your reply, I've added an expected output from the sample now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per what I understood, you need to find Bonus based on the success rate of the delivery boy.
For that first you need to filter out with the eligible one.

Considering your own example

```
data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
         'DeliveryOnTime': ["On-time", "Late", "Early", "On-time", "On-time", "Late", "Early", "Early", "Late"],
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Eligible'] = df['DeliveryOnTime'].isin(["On-time", "Early"])
df['Total Orders'] = df['DeliveryOnTime'].count() 

df.replace([True,False], [1,0],inplace=True)
per_courier_eligible = df.groupby('ID').agg({'Eligible': 'sum','Total Orders':'count'})
per_courier_eligible['Success Rate'] = per_courier_eligible['Eligible']/per_courier_eligible['Total Orders']
per_courier_eligible['Bonus'] = per_courier_eligible['Eligible']
per_courier_eligible['Bonus'].loc[(per_courier_eligible['Success Rate'] >= 0.95)] = per_courier_eligible['Eligible'] + 1.2
print(per_courier_eligible)
```

Comment: replace that statement with the following:
per_courier_eligible['Bonus'] = per_courier_eligible['Bonus'].where(per_courier_eligible['Success Rate'] >= 0.95, per_courier_eligible['Eligible'] * 1.2)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I didn't use your code but I used an element of filtering it through each ID for it to work. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Its good you could make your code work.

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem with the order of .mul and .where?

This worked when I tried to reproduce:

`df['Bonus'] = df['Eligible'].where(df['Success Rate'] >= 95).mul(1.2)`

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer but unfortunately it still multiplies those under 95 `Success Rate` even with it switched round.

Answer (score 0):

I used an element of what @Rupal Shah said by filtering it per ID for the `Success Rate` and `Bonus` pay to work.

All I had to do was create a `.groupby()`:

```
ID = df.groupby(['ID', 'Date']).agg({'Total Orders':'sum','Eligible': 'sum'})
```

After this, I changed any following syntaxes with calculations from `df.` to `ID.`e.g.

```
ID['Success Rate'] = (ID['Eligible']/ID['Total Orders'])*100
```